# No EJB found with interface of type when I try to inject a Bean

Tags: jsf, ejb, managed-bean

I try to make a simple login with JSF and Managed Beans, but when start the server returns the following error.

```
WFLYEJB0406: No EJB found with interface of type 'Controlador.UsuarioSessionBean' for binding Controlador.AlmacenVirtualBean/usuarioSession"}
```

This is the class to save the data...

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class UsuarioSessionBean implements Serializable  {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EJB
private UsuarioSessionDAO usuarioSession;

//private Usuario usuario;

private int usuarioId;
private String nick;
private String pass;
```

And in other Managed Bean I try to inject the first.

```
@ManagedBean(name="AlmacenVirtualBean")
@RequestScoped
public class AlmacenVirtualBean {

private AlmacenVirtual almacenVirtual;
private String nombre;
private int usuarioId;

public AlmacenVirtualBean(){}

@EJB
private AlmacenVirtualDAO almacenVirtualDAO;

@ManagedProperty("#{UsuarioSessionBean}")
private UsuarioSessionBean usuarioSession;
```

That's what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You may get that error, if you change the `AlmacenVirtualBean` to have:

```
@EJB
private UsuarioSessionBean usuarioSession;
```

Your question code can't produce that error.

But you can get `usuarioSession=null`. You should replace `#{UsuarioSessionBean}` by `#{usuarioSessionBean}`.